# iOS development: interactive graph

Tags: ios

[image]

Please take a look at the image above. The red circles represent user's touching motion. So if the user touched where the first circle is (to the left), then there should be a graph that's skewed to the left. If user touched in the middle, a normally distributed graph. If the user touches the right part, the graph should be skewed right.

I am new to iOS development and I am wondering how I can achieve such feature. Any recommendation to suitable libraries, frameworks, documents will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let's go through the components of that one at a time.

1. To know where the user touches, you could use something like a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` or `UITapGestureRecognizer`.
2. To draw a curve, a common technique is to add a `CAShapeLayer`:

   ```
   CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
   shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
   shapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
   shapeLayer.lineWidth = 4.0;
   [self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
   ```

   You can then set the `path` for that `CAShapeLayer`, and every time you change the `path`, the curve on the view will change. If you change that path frequently (e.g. you use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` that is called every time the user's finger moves), you are effectively animating the change of the curve.
3. So, how do you create the `path`? Well, you just create a `UIBezierPath`

   ```
   UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
   [path moveToPoint:...];

   // build the path as a series of curves
   //
   // [path addCurveToPoint:...
   //         controlPoint1:...
   //         controlPoint2:...];

   // or a series of lines that are so numerous that it looks like a nice curve
   //
   // for (NSInteger x = 0; x <= view.bounds.size.width; x++) {
   //     [path addLineToPoint:...];
   // }

   shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath;
   ```

   So, the only question is whether the curve needs to be a normal distribution, or whether you just want something that draws a smooth curve with a local maximum where the user touched.

   If you want something that exactly and mathematically represents some particular curve (e.g. if in the center, it's a true normal distribution), then you need to come up with the equation to represent your curve (as a function of where the user tapped). Then you draw your curve by plotting a whole bunch of points using `addLineToPoint` with a `UIBezierPath`.

   If you only need something that looks close, then you can approximate it with two bezier paths (created with `addCurveToPoint:controlPoint1:controlPoint2:`).

We're not going to write this for you, but these are the basic building blocks of the solution. I'd suggest you take these one at a time, do a little research on each, try it out, and then refine. Start small and build from there.